# Which environment variable contains…

Tags: linux, bash

…pseudo terminal file name associated to a terminal emulator window? I accidentally found it, just typed something like

```
$ echo $SOMETHING
/dev/pts/4
```

but forgot that variable, I googled it, looked in man pages, in ~/bash_history, but there are only commands of the first opened terminal and they're very old (~half a day) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the tty command:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/3
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the current tty you can use the `tty` command

```
[sr@panther ~]$ echo "Your current TTY is $(tty)"
Your current TTY is /dev/pts/5
```

Or you can set it to a variable manually if you want

```
MYTTY=`tty`
echo $MYTTY
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an environment variable with some special value you can do:

```
env | grep "the value you look for"
```

Comment: I’ve tried grepping `env`. Nothing there contained such a value.